# Let $\sum x_n$ be conditionally convergent in $\Bbb R$. Show that $\sum x_n^+$ and $\sum x_n^-$ diverge.

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> Let $\sum x_n$ be conditionally convergent in $\Bbb R$. Show that $\sum x_n^+$ and $\sum x_n^-$ diverge.

where $x_n^+=\max\{x_n,0\}$ and $x_n^-=\max\{-x_n,0\}$. Check the validity of this proof please.

If $\sum x_n^+$ and $\sum x_n^-$ would be both convergent then

$$\sum_{k=j}^n x_n^+ +\sum_{k=j}^n x_n^-=\sum_{k=j}^n |x_n|\implies \lim \left(\sum_{k=j}^n x_n^+ +\sum_{k=j}^n x_n^-\right)=\sum_{k=j}^\infty |x_n|$$

what is a contradiction to the condition of $\sum x_n$ being conditionally convergent. Then at least one of the "subseries" must be divergent.

Now I will show that both must be divergent. Without lose of generality suppose that $\sum x_n^+$ converges and $\sum x_n^-$ diverges. Then

$$\sum_{k=j}^n x_n^+ -\sum_{k=j}^n x_n^-=\sum_{k=j}^n x_n\implies \lim \left(\sum_{k=j}^n x_n^+ -\sum_{k=j}^n x_n^-\right)=\sum_{k=j}^\infty x_n$$

then $\sum x_n$ diverges, what is a contradiction.$\Box$